# Power series representation of $(1+x^2)\arctan x$

Tags: calculus, power-series

so i've been looking for a cleaner way of solving this question, finding a Power series representation of the following:
$$
\left(1+x^2\right)\arctan\left(x\right) 
$$
knowing the power series of arctan i got:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty \:}\frac{\left(-1\right)^n\cdot x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\:+\:\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^n\cdot \:x^{2n+3}}{2n+1}
$$
which after opening up the sum expressions amounts to :
$$
x+\:\:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^n\cdot \:2\cdot x^{2n+1}}{\left(2n\right)^2-1}
$$

I am sure there is a better way of doing this, maybe differentiation or integration? I've tried but i can't figure it out.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :]

Comment: IMO this is the most straightforward way, nothing "not clean". This generalizes to the product of an arbitrary polynomial and an arbitrary entire series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is indeed a solution by differentiation + integration:

Differentiate your expression:

$$2x \arctan(x) +1$$

replace $\arctan(x)$ by its expansion, then integrate it term by term... taking into account the integration constant in such a way that there is an agreement in $x=0$ of the initial expression and your expansion.

Answer (score 1):

If we have a polynomial of the form:

$$ P(x) = \sum a_i x^i$$

Another one of form:

$$ Q(x)  = \sum b_j x^j$$

$$ P(x) \cdot Q(x) = \sum a_i \cdot b_j x^{i+j}$$

Sub :

$$ i+j = u$$

Leads to:

$$ i= u-j$$

$$ P(x) \cdot Q(x)  = \sum_{u=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^u a_{u-j} b_j x^u$$

Or, r.h.s:

$$ \sum_{u=0}^{\infty} x^u \sum_{j=0}^u a_{u-j} b_j$$

Now call:

$$  \sum_{j=0}^u a_{u-j} b_j =  c_u$$

Or,

$$ \sum_{j=0}^u a_j b_{u-j} = c_u$$

For this particular case:

$$ a= \{ a_0 , a_1, a_2 ,0  ,0 , 0 ,0 ,0... \} =  \{ 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 ....\}$$

Hence:

$$  (1) b_{u} + (1)b_{u-2} = c_u$$

Now:

$$ u \to 2k+1$$

Or,

$$ b_{2k+1}  + b_{2k-1} = c_{2k+1}$$

For the $ \tan^{-1} $ series:

$$ b_{2k+1} = \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$$

And,

$$ b_{2k-1} = \frac{ (-1)^{k-1} }{ 2k-1}$$

Hence:

$$ c_{2k+1} = \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1} + \frac{ (-1)^k}{2k+1}$$

Hence our series is:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_{2k+1} x^{2k+1}$$
DONE!